# Custom Middleware - 'Too Many Redirects' - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, middleware, laravel-middleware

I want to create a custom middleware that only if the user is authenticated and the email is a certain email to access the /admin page.

Although, when I specify my custom route and then a redirect it always says too many redirects..

***Short Explanation.***

1. User Logs in -> redirected to /home. (Works)
2. If user tries to access /admin and their email isn't like the one specified in the middleware, redirect to /home.
3. If its true, let them in /admin

My middleware is called 'admin.verify'

**Routes File:**

```
Route::get('/admin', 'AdminController@index')->name('admin.index');
```

**AdminController:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct(){
      $this->middleware(['auth', 'admin.verify']);
    }


    public function index(){
      return view('admin.test');
    }
}
```

**Middleware:**

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

      if (Auth::check() && Auth::User()->email == 'Tester@gmail.com') {
        return $next($request);
      } else {
        return redirect()->route('home');
      }
```

My Home Route:

```
 GET|HEAD | home | home| App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index | web,auth
```

Home Controller:

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('home');
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the definition of your `home` route.

Comment: Your middleware should be within the Routes file not in the Controller

Comment: @Option Why do you say that? Adding a [middleware to a controller](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/controllers#controller-middleware) is valid.

Comment: Added more info to question

Comment: Where is the `auth` middleware redirecting to if the user is not authenticated? Could it be that is redirecting to the same `home` route?

Comment: @Camilo, You can add middleware to controller yes, but why write the same thing over and over again if the middleware ends up having to be used for multiple controllers? Please note that I never said it wasn't valid I said it should go in the routes section.

Comment: @Option It really depends on the case, some times it makes more sense having it in the controller.

Comment: @Camilo, completely disagree with that statement. The same as I disagree with your question in the answer below. ^_^

Comment: @Option There will only be one admin controller, hence it makes sense just to place it under the construct. Although, you are right if there are multiple controllers.

Comment: @pegasus, problem I see with this is if in future you wish to expand you have to then modify heavily.. Why not make easier from the get go?

Comment: @Option Either or works for me, my only concern right now if why I get all these redirects

Answer (score 1):

Use `$this->middleware ('admin.verify')` instead of `$this->middleware(['auth, admin.verify]');`. You are getting too many redirects error because both the admin middleware and the constructor are checking if the user is authenticated.

Comment: I had that originally, still did nothing. Same Error.

Comment: Why is a problem having both middlewares checking if the user is authenticated?

Comment: It was just for a test, dont worry about it.. I removed it!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you access home route auth.verify method is called and when it fails it is redirected to home itself creating a loop hence too many redirects error.

Change else condition in auth.verify middleware to redirect to another page like /login